# Basic usage of execlp() in C

Tags: multithreading, exec

So I was given this code:

```
execlp("sh", "sh", "-c", string, (char*) 0);
```

In class, and told to udnerstand it. I've been looking up the execlp API like crazy, but I still don't fully understand what this code is doing.

My best guess:
"sh" is the filepath

"-c" is the argument

string is the command

(char*)0 is the null terminator.

I can't seem to figure out why there are two instances of "sh" in the code:
I was guessing that -c means copy, and that the command is executing a copy from one file to another, using the string command, but I'm not 100% on that.

Any clarification would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: By convention, `argv[0]` is the name of the executable.

Comment: Ah okay, so "sh" would be the executable. Why is "sh" represented twice then?

Comment: The first argument is the actual command that you execute. Subsequent arguments populate `argv`, starting at zero.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first argument is the file name to execute (in this case it's the sh command). The first argument to it should be the name of the executable (hence the repeated "sh"), -c is another argument to the sh exe that tells it to read commands from the command string. string is (I'm guessing) the commands that sh should execute and the (char *)0 is just an ending marker.

Let me know if I left something out you wanted explained.

Comment: oh man thank you, that was great. Just a point of curiosity: this command would create a new process image that would overwrite the process image of the process that called it, right? So if process A called this execlp() command to execute program B, then the process associated with program B would overwrite process A?

Comment: Yes any process that executes an exec* command will be replaced by the process it tries to create. If you want to spawn a new process in this manner to keep Process A, use fork() to create Process B and then call exec in the context of Process B (by examining fork() return value)